# How to show arrows in backward and forward directions in a ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `dataframe` with coordinates of arrows:

```
arrows = data.frame(direction = factor(c("forward", "backward", "backward")),
                x = c(0, 0, 0),
                xend = c(1, 1, 1),
                y = c(1, 1.2, 1.1),
                yend = c(1, 1.2, 1.1))
```

I want to use this data to plot arrows - some goes in the forward direction and vice versa.

So far I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
        geom_segment(data = arrows, 
                     aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, col = direction),
                     arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", ends = c("last", "first")))
```

which produces:

[image]

There are 2 problems I want to solve in this plot:

1. How can I make sure that `ggplot` 'understands' which plot is "forward" and "backward", so it gives them the right legend?
2. How to change the legend so that it shows forward direction with an arrow that goes forward, and the backward arrow that goes backward?

Comment: All the answers below (so far) nicely solves the color problem in the legend. At this point I am mostly interested showing the directions properly in the legend: backward direction should go backward, and forward direction should be shown forward in the legend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps with two legends, one using a custom glyph?

[image]

```
draw_key_arrow_left <- function(data, params, size, dir) {
  if (is.null(data$linetype)) {
    data$linetype <- 0
  } else {
    data$linetype[is.na(data$linetype)] <- 0
  }
  
  segmentsGrob(0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5,
               gp = gpar(
                 col = alpha(data$colour %||% data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha),
                 # the following line was added relative to the ggplot2 code
                 fill = alpha(data$colour %||% data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha),
                 lwd = (data$size %||% 0.5) * .pt,
                 lty = data$linetype %||% 1,
                 lineend = "butt"
               ),
               arrow = params$arrow
  )
}


arrows2 <- arrows %>%
  mutate(x_orig = x, xend_orig = xend,
         x = if_else(direction == "forward", x_orig, xend_orig),
         xend = if_else(direction == "forward", xend_orig, x_orig))

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = arrows2 %>% filter(direction == "forward"),
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, col = direction),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "#F8766D") +
  
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_segment(data = arrows2 %>% filter(direction == "backward"),
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, col = direction),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed"),
               key_glyph = "arrow_left") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "#619CFF", name = "") +
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(0.7,"cm"))
```

Comment: this is certainly a nice workaround too around [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72784232/defining-modifying-data-for-draw-key?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Great solution! Do you know how I could minimise the distance between the forward and backward arrows? At the moment it looks a bit weird to have this much distance :)

Comment: If the legend title isn't important, you could change the font size for both legend titles to be tiny with `theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 1))`

Answer (score 3):

The ends argument needs to be set for each arrow, yours is only length two so that last arrow will be the wrong direction since it is using the default which is "last" but since the arrow goes backwards it should be "first"

```
arrows <- data.frame(direction = (c("forward", "backward", "backward")),
                    x = c(0, 0, 0),
                    xend = c(1, 1, 1),
                    y = c(1, 1.2, 1.1),
                    yend = c(1, 1.2, 1.1))

arrow_head <- function(direction) {
  if(direction == "backward") {
    return("first")
  } else {
    return("last")
  }
}

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = arrows,
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, col = direction),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", ends = lapply(arrows$direction, arrow_head)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about mapping the "direction" to "first" and "last" directly, e.g.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = arrows, 
                 aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend, col = direction),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", ends = ifelse(arrows$direction == "forward", "first", "last" ))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkblue"), labels = c("forward", "backward"))
```

I'd also used a `scale_colour_manual` to control which direction is forward and which backward.

Another question on SO asked about custom glyphs in legends - [show filled arrow in legend ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193353/show-filled-arrow-in-legend-ggplot) - This should allow the different arrow direction, but might not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

You could swap the column values in x/xend based on the direction column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
arrows = data.frame(direction = factor(c("forward", "backward", "backward")),
                    x = c(0, 0, 0),
                    xend = c(1, 1, 1),
                    y = c(1, 1.2, 1.1),
                    yend = c(1, 1.2, 1.1))

## thanks for the idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096664/how-to-do-conditional-swapping-using-two-columns
swap_direction <- function(data){
  swap <- data$direction == "backward"
  v1 <- data$x
  v2 <- data$xend
  data$x[swap] <- v2[swap]
  data$xend[swap] <- v1[swap]
  data
}
reversed_arrows <- swap_direction(arrows)

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = reversed_arrows, 
               aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, col = direction),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>